# SwiftMailer yahoo smtp error

Tags: php, email, slim, swiftmailer

Lately i have been trying to connect to an smtp server from my php app.I have chosen the SwiftMailer library for this,but it just doesn't seem to work.I have tried to connect to both gmail and yahoo servers(since i have accounts on both platforms),but I keep getting the same error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mail.yahoo.com [ #0]

In a nutshell,this is my code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('password')
;

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom(['alin_cycling@yahoo.com' => 'Dima Alin'])
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
;

$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: that means you're not even reaching the server. e.g. something's blocking the connection, like a firewall.

Comment: oh,and what can i do about it?

Comment: figure out where the blockage is.

Comment: if you could explain a little what how exatcly should I do that,i would be very grateful